# I have a really hard time with sscanf and fscanf in C

Tags: c

I am trying to scan a string in from a file, but it seems the `fscanf()` only scans two things and I cannot understand why.

```
struct rider_profile array_assembler(FILE *fp){
    struct rider_profile new_profile;
    char buffer[150];
    int check;

    check = fscanf(fp, "%s \"%[^\"]\" %d %[A-Z] %[A-Z] %[0-9DNFOTL] %[0-9:]",
        new_profile.bike_race,
        new_profile.full_name,
        new_profile.rider_team,
        new_profile.rider_nationality,
        new_profile.placement_in_race,
        new_profile.race_time);

    printf("should be 7: %d", check);// it is only the first two that get scand.
    return new_profile;
}
```

The string that I am trying to scan in is:

```
ParisRoubaix "Greg VAN AVERMAET" | 32 BMC BEL | 1 5:41:07
```

Comment: There are characters in that string not matched by that pattern.

Comment: You are ignoring the `'|'` characters. Also, with the 3rd one, `%d`, you need to pass the address of an int: `&new_profile.rider_team`.  Lastly, you expect 7 items but only pass 6 args.

Comment: `new_profile` definition missing.

Comment: If it is any consolation, the `scanf()` family of functions are just about the most complex functions in the standard C library — they are extraordinarily difficult to use well in anything but the simplest situations (but there are simple situations where they're OK).  Using `fgets()` and `sscanf()` is usually a good step towards sanity.  You might read [A Beginner's Guide Away From `scanf()`](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear *exactly* how you want the grouping to go, but you have to account for the `|`.

I had to guess as to how to group `32 BMC BEL` -- there's probably a better way to do it than what I came up with:

Here's some code that gets you closer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct rider_profile {
    char bike_race[100];
    char full_name[100];
    char rider_team_number[100];
    char rider_team[100];
    char rider_nationality[100];
    char placement_in_race[100];
    char race_time[100];
};

struct rider_profile
array_assembler(FILE * fp)
{
    struct rider_profile new_profile;
    int check;

    check = fscanf(fp, "%100s \"%100[^\"]\" %*[|] %100[0-9] %100[A-Z] %100[A-Z] %*[|] %100[0-9DNFOTL] %100[0-9:]",
        new_profile.bike_race,
        new_profile.full_name,
        new_profile.rider_team_number,
        new_profile.rider_team,
        new_profile.rider_nationality,
        new_profile.placement_in_race,
        new_profile.race_time);

    printf("should be 7: %d\n", check); // it is only the first two that get scand.

    printf("test: bike_race='%s'\n",new_profile.bike_race);
    printf("test: full_name='%s'\n",new_profile.full_name);
    printf("test: rider_team_number='%s'\n",new_profile.rider_team_number);
    printf("test: rider_team='%s'\n",new_profile.rider_team);
    printf("test: rider_nationality='%s'\n",new_profile.rider_nationality);
    printf("test: placement_in_race='%s'\n",new_profile.placement_in_race);
    printf("test: race_time='%s'\n",new_profile.race_time);

    return new_profile;
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    FILE *fi = fopen(*argv,"r");
    array_assembler(fi);

    fclose(fi);

    return 0;
}
```

The output for your sample input is:

```
should be 9: 9
test: bike_race='ParisRoubaix'
test: full_name='Greg VAN AVERMAET'
test: rider_team_number='32'
test: rider_team='BMC'
test: rider_nationality='BEL'
test: placement_in_race='1'
test: race_time='5:41:07'
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> Width specifiers for %s and %[], please

```
fscanf(fp, "%100s \"%100[^\"]\" %*[|] %100[0-9] %100[A-Z] %100[A-Z] %*[|] %100[0-9DNFOTL] %100[0-9:]"
```

Comment: Width specifiers for `%s` and `%[]`, please. For ignored conversions add a `*`: `%*s`, `%*[abc]` no need for a variable.

Comment: With, e.g. `char bike_race[100];`, `%99s` is needed since `scanf()` automatically writes a `\0` character to terminate the string. This tells `scanf()` to write at most 99 characters into the array before the mandatory null terminator. `%100s` risks buffer overflow.

Comment: What is the benefit of using `%*[|]` instead of just `|`?